# JSon Parsing in Angular Model Declaration

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I  build a Model and parse JSON data but there is problem of parsing.

My JSON data looks like this:

```
{
    "receiptNo": [
        {
            "_id": "5ba6101964991b2f44e1c9cf",
            "receiptNo": "21471",
            "rollno": 122,
            "bankcode": 2,
            "userid": "rifat",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

And, this is my model for angular:

```
export class ReceiptModel
{
    receiptNo: String;
}
```

Please note that I want to get the `receiptNo` but unable to get.

How to declare model for this specific JSON?

Comment: In your JSON, `receiptNo` is an array, not a string.

Answer (score 1):

In TypeScript the property `receiptNo: String;` will be expecting a string.

Your data has an Array as the value of this property, so it will not be a good fit.

You might want to create a `Receipt` class and change your current class to:

```
export class ReceiptModel
{
    receiptNo: Receipt[];
}
```

So to access the number from within the array, assuming you have a model like this:

```
export class Receipt
{
    receiptNo: String;
}
```

you would have to get an element of that array:

```
const data: ReceiptModel;
data = <your data here>;
const aReceipt = data.receiptNo[0]; //Just getting the first one

//now the receipt number can be accessed via:
aReceipt.receiptNo
```

Comment: Then How I get receiptNo inside the array